# ながらも followed up by のに

Tags: parsing

> 恥ずかしそうに戸惑いながらも、彼女は快楽の波を声に出して逃すのに忙しそうだ。

Though she is bewildered in shame, (and though??) her waves of pleasure escape in her voice, she seems flustered.

i'm not sure if this is only because using though b2b is strange in English, but there is a certain logical disconnect here.

Thank you for any clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, the 「のに」 is about the 「声に出して逃がす」.
The role that 「の」 plays here is the same as 「こと」.

> Example:食べるのに夢中である　= 食べることに夢中である

So, to translate your example:

> 恥ずかしそうに戸惑いながらも、彼女は快楽の波を声に出して逃すのに忙しそうだ。
>
> Even though she is hesitant from embarrassment, she seems busy letting escape vocalizations of the waves of pleasure

*Naruto pointed out that the 「逃がす」 in this example is transitive and therefore my initial translation was incorrect. I have corrected the translation to reflect the correction.

*It should be noted that my translation is still not 100% accurate, grammar-wise. What is being let escape is not 「声」, but 「快楽の波」. 「声」 is simply the method by which the escape is being let happen. I worded it this way because it sounds more natural, but the exact translation would be as worded by naruto in the comment below.

Comment: This 逃す is transitive ("to vent/dissipate the waves of pleasure by vocalizing it").

Comment: @naruto Thank you for pointing out the incorrect translation of 「逃がす」. I have improved the answer accordingly.

Comment: This 快楽の波を逃がす is like how a relief valve does 圧力を逃がす or a heat sink does 熱を逃がす to protect the entire system. Basically her pleasure is so strong and explosive that she has to release it as a voice to protect herself.

Comment: Keep talking like that, I'm going to start thinking your translation of that book will be more erotic than the actual book itself

Answer (score 0):

What is this? Porn?

恥ずかしそうに戸惑いながらも、彼女は快楽の波を声に出して逃すのに忙しそうだ。
Even though she was embarrassed, she looked too busy letting out loud waves of pleasure.

Comment: I would guess eroge.